# Pandas Regex to Remove Preceding Characters and Column

Tags: python, pandas

The output of the Pandas Dataframe using the following code:

```
payload={}
files={}
headers = {
  'Accept': 'text/csv',
  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +token}

for k in request_dic.keys():
  base_url = "https://feeds.myfeed.com/api/"
  url = base_url + request_dic[k]
  print(url)

  response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)


  dt = pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text),sep="|", encoding='base64')
```

Is:

[image]

Can someone help with a regex that will remove Ã¯Â»Â¿

Comment: if it's just that one column, you could just rename it

Comment: I understand you're logic, but I'm this is For Loop on a number of tables.. May be I should insert the full code for clarity

Comment: could you just put the code to rename in the loop?

Comment: Yes, but one CSV has name country, another has the name company etc...

Comment: well you could check that all the letters in each column headers are in `string.ascii_uppercase`, and then fix them if not

Comment: SuperStew, thanks for reaching out. Do you have an example.

Comment: In a nutshell I just need help replacing Ã¯Â»Â¿ with a blank... and that is it - nothing more.

Comment: put an answer that might do it

Comment: forgot to add axis arg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this maybe

```
import re
for k in request_dic.keys():
    base_url = "https://feeds.myfeed.com/api/"
    url = base_url + request_dic[k]
    print(url)

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)


    dt = pd.read_csv(StringIO(response.text),sep="|", encoding='base64')

    for col in dt.columns:
        dt.rename({col:re.findall('([A-Z].*)',col)[0]},inplace=True,axis=1)
```

Comment: doesn't this code remove numbers or characters like ( or )?

Comment: true. didn't sound like that was OPs issue

Comment: Seems like removing the `*` from the regex will cut out numbers or other chars if you want

Answer (score 0):

```
"".join([ch for ch in "Ã¯Â»Â¿COUNTRY ID" if str.isascii(ch)]).strip()
```

I prefer it, use something like it in `rename` method, like @SuperStew does

Answer (score 0):

Since you specifically ask for a regex, the following line will remove any characters which are not (`^`) in the upper- or lowercase alphabet (`A-Za-z`) and not a whitespace (`\s`).

```py
dt.columns = dt.columns.str.replace('[^A-Za-z\s]', '')
```

If you have non-ASCII characters in your regular column names, you might need to adjust the regex. If you also need numbers you could add `0-9` to the regex.

Result:

|  | COUNTRY ID | COUNTRY NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 10 | Greece |
| 1 | 10007 | Romania |